# Problemas ao migrar site em CakePHP entre servidores

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

Estou tentando migrar o site entre servidores, porém para validar o funcionamento do site, baixei e estou tentando instalar no `Wamp`. Não tenho experiência com o `framework Cake`.

Já fiz a exclusão dos arquivos na pasta de cache e diz a configuração do banco de dados database.php do subdiretório `Config de App`, porém o site não está carregando o Layout, Java scripts etc.

Onde é necessário alterar dentro do `Cake` para tornar isso possível? Se não for no Cake, deve ser alguma configuração de `htacess`. Porém há diversas delas, em que caminho seria? Não tenho certeza se o problema está sendo por dar erro 404 nos `assets` (`javascript, css`). Porém penso que até pode ser porque não estou conseguindo chamar outros `controllers`.

Log do console no Navegador:

> ```
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/site/js/application.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/logo-250x86.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/facebook-32x32.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/lancamentos.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/bacias.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/baldes.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/site/css/linhas/baldes.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/banheiro.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/cabides-e-prendedores.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/cozinha.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/jardim.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/maletas.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/moveis.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/cestos.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/organizadores.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/pallets.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/porta-isca.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/seletivas.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/green-seal.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/telados.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/newMenu/lancamentos.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/newMenu/bacias.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/newMenu/baldes.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/newMenu/banheiro.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/newMenu/cestos.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/newMenu/cabides-e-prendedores.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/newMenu/cozinha.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/newMenu/jardim.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/newMenu/maletas.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/newMenu/moveis.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/newMenu/organizadores.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/newMenu/pallets.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/newMenu/porta-isca.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/newMenu/seletivas.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/newMenu/telados.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/home/giardino.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/home/cestos.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/home/seletivas.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/home/banners/MAISALEGRIA-CestosCidades.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/home/banners/MAISEMOCAO-ConjuntosMesasCadeiras.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/home/banners/MAISNOVIDADE-ContaineresCidades.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/home/banners/Banner-100Porcento.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/home/banners/Banner-Dia.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/home/banners/Banner-Reciclar.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/files/noticia/imagem/60/normal.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/files/noticia/imagem/59/normal.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/files/noticia/imagem/58/normal.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/novo.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/files/produtos/179/main-211.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/grey-cart.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/files/produtos/161/main-211.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/files/produtos/155/main-211.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/files/produtos/168/main-211.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/reciclar-garantir-vida.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/amandaduz-sign-01.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/crazy-btn.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/cart.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/logo-250x86.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/site/js/application.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> localhost/:1177 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
> http://localhost/images/facebook-32x32.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/lancamentos.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/bacias.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/images/linhas/buttons/baldes.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=1389913131244089&domain=loc…6%26relation%3Dparent&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&sdk=joey Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
> https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?action=like&app_id=13899131312440…ut=button_count&locale=pt_BR&sdk=joey&send=false&show_faces=false&width=70 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
> https://www.facebook.com/impression.php/f1d3e442c15f1a4/?api_key=1389913131244089&lid=115&payload=%7B%22source%22%3A%22jssdk%22%7D Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
> http://localhost/site/css/application.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/site/css/linhas/baldes.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> ```

Comment: Abra o console do navegador copiei todos erros que aparecem quando abrir a página, **edite a pergunta**, cole o log e aguarde.

Comment: Desta forma acima?

Comment: Em app/Config/core.php altere o debug para 2 ->  Configure::write('debug', 2);

Comment: poste o htaccess e veja também se tem algo relevante no log de erro do apache

Comment: Sou um desenvolvedor Cake, e apesar dos erros citados isso só mostra o problema, recomendo você copiar e colar o htacess aqui, porém como já funcionava no outro, e deveria somente funcionar no novo servidor, pedirei que relate qual é a versão do cake, caso seja a 3 é necessário instalar o composer e fazer algumas configurações iniciais, o cake3 já usa psr-4 então, necessária mente ele precisará criar algumas definições. lembre-se dos requisitos para funcionamento do cake, mbstring, curl, intl, e o modo rewrite deve estar ativo.

Comment: Poste o conteúdo do .htaccess para analise. Falo por experiência própria, na maioria dos casos o problema está no modo rewrite não está ativo.

Comment: Pode ser algum problema de permissão deste arquivos tambem.